# Python Prettytable Separating Each Table

Tags: python, prettytable

I have a little question. How I can split the table if they have the same column name?

This is the example:

```
+----------------------------+
|       AUDIO TRACKS         |
+----+----------+------------+
| ID | LangCode | LangName   |
+----+----------+------------+
| 1  | de       | German     |
| 2  | de       | German     |
| 3  | en       | English    | 
| 4  | en       | English    |
| 5  | es       | Spanish    |
| 6  | es       | Spanish    |
+----------------------------+
```

This is my desired output

```
+----------------------------+
|       AUDIO TRACKS         |
+----+----------+------------+
| ID | LangCode | LangName   |
+----+----------+------------+
| 1  | de       | German     |
| 2  | de       | German     |
|----------------------------|
| 3  | en       | English    | 
| 4  | en       | English    |
|----------------------------|
| 5  | es       | Spanish    |
| 6  | es       | Spanish    |
+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and after each group add split_row like below:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from itertools import groupby

myTable = PrettyTable(["ID", "LongCode", "LangName"])
  
lst = [["1", "de", "German"], ["2", "de", "German"], 
       ["3", "en", "English"], ["4", "en", "English"],
       ["5", "es", "Spanish"], ["4", "es", "Spanish"]]

split_row = ['—' * x for x in [2, 8, 10]]

myTable.title = 'AUDIO TRACKS'
for key, group in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[1]):
    for g in group:
        myTable.add_row(g)
    myTable.add_row(split_row)
print(myTable)
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+
|        AUDIO TRACKS        |
+----+----------+------------+
| ID | LongCode |  LangName  |
+----+----------+------------+
| 1  |    de    |   German   |
| 2  |    de    |   German   |
| —— | ———————— | —————————— |
| 3  |    en    |  English   |
| 4  |    en    |  English   |
| —— | ———————— | —————————— |
| 5  |    es    |  Spanish   |
| 4  |    es    |  Spanish   |
| —— | ———————— | —————————— |
+----+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) this is what I'm looking for.
What i did just a little for split_row, because I have so many columns, is multiply the dash :)

Comment: @mark12345 edited answer